# Why is my random effect down-weighing certain ORs?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model

I'm running a mixed-effect logistic regression using data from 21 different sites. One of my key variables of interest is a six-level factor variable. I've included a random effect of site into the model, as well to account for the clustering of respondents in each site.

I noticed when I remove the random effect, certain ORs for the six-level factor become inflated. When I include the random effect, these same ORs shrink.

I'm wondering if someone can offer a simple explanation for this. Many thanks.

EDIT: Including partial model output below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any missing data ? And are you saying that some of the odds ratios change but some stay unchanged ?

Comment: There are a handful of sites where respondents only answered 0, or 1 (i.e., unbalanced in certain sites). In some sites, including where we see unbalanced responses, the sample size is small. I would expect some change with the inclusion of the random effect, but we're observing a fairly large shift in magnitude for certain variables with and without the RE.

Edit: To answer your edited question -- yes, some of the ORs change, but some remain relatively stable within the six-level factor we are interested in.

Comment: When you say "relatively stable" you mean that they also change, just by less than the others ? So you don't have a situation where some estimates change but others are (excatly) unchanged [that would be unusual]? With unbalanced designs and missing data, it's fairly common to see this. Perhaps you can edit your question and include all the relevant model output ?

Comment: Yes. What you said is correct -- relatively stable = they change, but it's far far less. I can post the model output, as well.

Comment: @RobertLong: Thanks. I've included the output above. I understand that it's fairly common for this to happen; wondering if you could offer a brief perspective on why it happens.

Comment: No worries. Those are farily substantial differences !!! More information is needed - sample sizes, groups sizes, random effects estimates, the exact model that you've fitted. Even with this it might be tough to get to the bottom of, without access to the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to your sampling unit.  Using a random site effect changes what you are making inference on.  *Without* a random site effect you are making inference on a population of respondents who visit these sites.  With a random site effect you are no longer making inference on respondents, you are making inference on a broader population of sites from which your collection of sites were sampled.  The respondents at a site are considered repeated measurements on that site, and the endpoint and odds ratio pertains to sites.

While sites can certainly be heterogeneous, and outcomes on subjects who visit the same site may be correlated, I am not a fan of accounting for this using random effects.  Heterogeneity alone does not constitute a random variable, it is your sampling scheme that determines what is random.

If you have repeated measurements on each subject then you could include subject as a random effect since the subjects were sampled from a population of subjects, and it is this population of subjects that you want to make inference on.